# Why `apt-get dist-upgrade` in EC2 image does not update the kernel?

Tags: apt, kernel, amazon-ec2

I've built a system running Ubuntu 14.04 on EC2, using the AMI from Ubuntu's cloud-images repository. The AMI includes kernel 3.13.0-37, but 3.13.0-39 is available as an update.

After running `apt-get dist-upgrade` the new `linux-image` packages are downloaded and installed, but rebooting leaves me back in the old kernel.

I understand there was once need to get a special "ec2 kernel", but that is no longer available. How can I upgrade my EC2 VM's kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem only on "pv" (Para-virtualized) EC2 virtual machines. In such systems, the kernel has to be patched to be able to run on the default Xen DomU setup (which is PV). Hence "ec2 kernels", which you can't replace on a PV machine because that would break your system.

AWS have moved since to prefer HVM (Hardware Virtual Machine, which is the Xen term for virtualizing access to hardware devices using a hardware IOMMU, allowing native drivers in the virtual machine direct access to the hardware), so they stopped working hard on getting up to date EC2 specific kernels, and you should be able to use any kernel on an HVM virtual machine.